# How to format array in string

Tags: java, arrays, string, logging, format

I want to format log like this:

```
"order with orderid=1,orderid=2,orderid=3,orderid=4"
```

I have array with values `[1,2,3,4]`.
I understand that it is enough easy to use loop for this but I want to know if there is tool in jdk (or library) which can do this.

Comment: The amount of time to search such a library exceeds the time to just _create_ the loop by yourself...

Comment: @Murat K 1 time - yes, 100 times - no

Comment: So write it as a method.  The same logic (time spent searching > time writing) applies there too.  And besides, the answer is probably that there isn't one .... for something as specialized as this.

Comment: so you need a library which does something like this , `int[] array= {1,2,3,4};
  String formattedString = "order with orderid="+array[0]+",orderid="+array[1]+",orderid="+array[2]+",orderid="+array[3];` ? I am not sure if I misunderstood your question but you need to explain it better.

Comment: Why not live with "Order with orderid: {1, 2, 3, 4}"? `Arrays.toString(arr)` - often the array can passed as-is: `arr`.

Comment: @Joop Eggen I need splunk friendly format

Comment: @Sabir Khan size is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8:

```
int[] n = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
String orders = Arrays.stream(n).mapToObj(i -> "orderid=" + i).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
String result = "order with " + orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily build such a `String` using `for-loop`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //String append with orderid and array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as below way,

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       String strData[] = {"1","2","3"};
       String result = Arrays.toString(strData); // OutPut [1,2,3]

       result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1); // OutPut 1,2,3
       result = result.replaceAll(",", ", OrderId=");

       System.out.println("Order with OrderId=" + result);
       //OutPut Order with OrderId=1, OrderId=2
    }
```